# Informatica 9 How to map one output port to many input ports at once?

Tags: informatica

I have 1 output port, and I need to map it to many (say 100) input ports in the target. I can only do it by dragging it one by one, how can you do it all at once?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to export the mapping to XML, genenerate the needed  nodes and import the XML back.

Answer (score -1):

Can't understand why you need the same port persisted across 100 times to the same transformation... some explanation would help here... there is facility in Informatica to do Autolinking by name or position... it can also ignore suffixes / prefixes which differ between the 2 but as you have to specify each suffix / prefix, I dont see how that will help you in this instance